# Why does python `any` return a bool instead of the value?

Tags: python, function, internal

`and` and `or` return the last element they evaluated, but why doesn't Python's built-in function `any`?

I mean it's pretty easy to implement oneself like this, but I'm still left wondering why.

```
def any(l):
    for x in l:
        if x:
            return x
    return x
```

edit:

To add to the answers below, here's an actual quote from that same mailing list of ye mighty emperor on the issue:

> Whether to always return True and False or the first faling / passing
>   element? I played with that too before blogging, and realized that the
>   end case (if the sequence is empty or if all elements fail the test)
>   can never be made to work satisfactory: picking None feels weird if
>   the argument is an iterable of bools, and picking False feels weird if
>   the argument is an iterable of non-bool objects.
>
> Guido van Rossum (home page: http://www.python.org/~guido/)

Comment: As an aside, instead of writing your own, you can use `itertools.dropwhile().__next__()`

Comment: Related: [Reason for “all” and “any” result on empty lists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275058/)

Comment: Your example fails when `l` is empty?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

This very issue came up up on the Python developer's mailing list in 2005, when Guido Van Rossum proposed adding `any` and `all` to Python 2.5.

Bill Janssen [requested](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-March/052012.html) that they be implemented as

```
def any(S):
    for x in S:
        if x:
            return x
    return S[-1]

def all(S):
    for x in S:
        if not x:
            return x
    return S[-1]
```

Raymond Hettinger, who implemented `any` and `all`, [responded](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-March/052015.html) specifically addressing why `any` and `all` don't act like `and` and `or`:

> Over time, I've gotten feedback about these and other itertools recipes.
>   No one has objected to the True/False return values in those recipes or
>   in Guido's version.
>
> Guido's version matches the normal expectation of any/all being a
>   predicate.  Also, it avoids the kind of errors/confusion that people
>   currently experience with Python's unique implementation of "and" and
>   "or".
>
> Returning the last element is not evil; it's just weird, unexpected, and
>   non-obvious.  Resist the urge to get tricky with this one.

The mailing list largely concurred, leaving the implementation as you see it today.

Comment: Here's another nugget from the quoted discussion: Perl returns the last true/false value as well, and it is a subtle trap.
I worked at a perl shop that had a long style guide which outlawed using
that side effect but people did anyway.  I'm +1 on having it return a
true boolean for the same reason "if (x = calc_foo()):" isn't supported,
if there is a quirky side effect available someone will use it and someone
else won't notice.  (http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2005-March/052019.html)

Comment: Plus, returning the last element wouldn't work on an empty sequence.

Comment: @dan04:  Weeble's answer addresses that point nicely, so I'll leave that out of my answer for now.

Comment: "if there is a quirky side effect available someone will use it and someone else won't notice."--To avoid that factors out a few languages altogether--and I wholeheartedly agree.

Answer (score 22):

`and` and `or` can be sensibly defined in a way that they *always* return one of their operands. However, `any` and `all` cannot sensibly be defined always to return a value from their input sequence: specifically they cannot do so when the list is empty. Both `any` and `all` currently have a well defined result in this situation: `any` returns False and `all` returns True. You would be forced to *sometimes* return a boolean value and *sometimes* return an item from the sequence, which makes for an unpleasant and surprising interface. Much better to be simple and consistent.

Comment: I think *any* answer from `any()` or `all()` is a bit surprising.

Comment: You will set off the metal detector if `any(thing.ismetal for thing in yourpockets)`. You can post a soft bag through a slot if `all(item.maxdimension<=slot.size for item in bag)`. There are plenty of situations where the answer from `any([])` or `all([])` is entirely natural and unsurprising.

Comment: I'd think `any` could return `None` if the list is empty. But it's probably cleaner to simply return a bool and as you said an easier interface to deal with.

Comment: @doda So what would `all` return? It needs to both match `any` and be `True` in a boolean context.

Comment: @agf I'd use `True`, I don't see why it has to perfectly match `all`, they're different functions after all. I don't have a problem with the design decision of python's core team, after all Python makes it simple to roll your own if you so desire.

Comment: I disagree. If `sum` can have a default `start` value of `0`, why couldn't `all` have a default `start` value of `True`?

Answer (score 17):

Starting `Python 3.8`, and the introduction of [assignment expressions (PEP 572)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) (`:=` operator), we can alternatively explicitly capture a *witness* of an `any` expression or a *counterexample* of an `all` expression:

---

To quote a couple examples from the [PEP description](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/):

```
if any(len(long_line := line) >= 100 for line in lines):
  print("Extremely long line:", long_line)
```

```python
if all((nonblank := line).strip() == '' for line in lines):
  print("All lines are blank")
else:
  print("First non-blank line:", nonblank)
```

Answer (score 5):

I asked this same question [on python-ideas](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.ideas/11578), and was told the reason was that `any()` and `all()` need to return a value when the sequence is empty, and those values must be `False` and `True`. This seems like a weak argument to me.

The functions can't change now, but I think they would be more useful, and better analogs of the `and` and `or` operators they generalize, if they returned the first true-ish or false-ish value they encountered.

Comment: I think this is backwards. Any use case for `and` or `or` returning a value can be replaced with the conditional expression. Just because they're overloaded doesn't mean other things should be.

Comment: @agf The `and` and `or` behavior predates the conditional expression.

Comment: @phihag Yes, I know that. That's why they're overloaded. It makes sense for historical reasons. That doesn't mean "There should be only one way to do it" should be violated everywhere. Logically, `any` is a boolean question, so any other type of return value is unexpected.

Comment: @Ned Batchelder: See my answer for historical note.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of `and` and `or` exists for historical reasons.

Before Python had a ternary operation / conditional expression, you used `and` and `or` if you wanted to use a value on a condition. Any such expression can be rewritten with the conditional expression syntax:

```
true_val if condition else false_val
```

Essentially, they are overloaded with two functions, and for compatibility reasons, they haven't been changed.

That is *not* a reason to overload other operations. `any` seems like it should tell you *whether or not a condition is true for any item*, which is a boolean, so it should return a `bool`.

Comment: +1.  This dove-tails nicely with my answer.  I think that perhaps `and` and `or` not returning boolean is for more than just backwards compatability.  If my reading between the lines of PEP 285 is correct, Guido seems to prefer the non-purity of `and` and `or`.

Answer (score 0):

`Any` returns a boolean because it effectively treats its argument as a list of bools before considering if any of them are true. It *is* returning the element it evaluates, but this happens to be a bool.

When would you want to use your version of `any`? If it's on a list of bools then you already have the correct answer. Otherwise you are just guarding against `None` and might be expressed as:

```
filter(lambda x: x != None, l)[0]
```

or:

```
[x for x in l if x != None][0]
```

Which is a clearer statement of intent.

Comment: `any` doesn't convert to `bool` any more or less than `and` and `or`. That's not it.

Comment: `and` and `or` do treat their arguments as `bool`. They are exceptional in the fact that they return one of their arguments.

Comment: But why are they exceptional and not `any`?

Comment: Presumably because there would be no benefit and it allows more optimisations in the implementation.

Comment: *Speculatively*, rather than presumably.

Comment: It's not hard to see how dropping the requirement of returning an element allows for potentially more efficient implementation (e.g. anding a list of ints rather than comparing). I do concede that my presumption was speculative.

Answer (score 0):

It's not immediately obvious that `any`'s value could be either False or one of the values in the input. Also, most uses would look like

```
tmp = any(iterable)
if tmp:
   tmp.doSomething()
else:
   raise ValueError('Did not find anything')
```

That's [Look Before You Leap](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-lbyl) and therefore unpythonic. Compare to:

```
next(i for i in iterable if i).doSomething()
# raises StopIteration if no value is true
```

The behavior of `and` and `or` was historically useful as a drop-in for the then-unavailable conditional expression.

Comment: This doesn't explain why it's different from `and` and `or`. The same argument could be made for them.

Comment: Updated. Perhaps @RaymondHettinger can shed some light - he commited `any` and `all`.

Comment: @phihag: Raymond Hettinger does shed some light in my answer. :)