# Why don't Python's any/all return the found objects?

Tags: python, api, monads, any

The Python `and` and `or` operators, return values, rather than `True` or `False`, which is useful for things such as:

```
x = d.get(1) or d.get(2) or d.get(3)
```

Which will make `x` the value of `d[1]`, `d[2]` or `d[3]` which ever is present. This is a bit like having an additive Maybe monad in functional languages.

I've always wanted that the python `any()` function would be more like a repeated `or`. I think it would make sense return the object it finds, like:

```
any([None, None, 1, 2, None]) == 1
any(notnull_iterator) = try: return next(notnull_iterator); except: return None
```

And likewise for `all()`. It seems to me the change would be entirely backwards compatible, and increase consistency across the API.

Does anyone know of a previous discussion of this topic?

Comment: Actually, in your example - if `d[1]` is a Falsey value, it will process to `d[2]` etc. In that case, to be safe you could use `x = d.get(1, d.get(2, d.get(3)))` however, unfortunately that won't short circuit

Comment: That's true, but often enough I find my data structures populated with my own objects, that are never `None`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you're looking for

```
first = lambda s: next((x for x in s if x), None)
```

e.g.

```
first([None, None,1, 2,None]) # 1
```

The "why" question is answered over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10180344/989121).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> my_any = partial(reduce, lambda x, y:x or y)
>>> my_any([None, None, 1, 2, None])
1

>>> my_all = partial(reduce, lambda x, y:x and y)
>>> my_all([0, 0, 1, 2, 0])
0
```

In the above example, `my_all([])` raises an exception. However, you can easily provide a default value instead

```
>>> my_all([], "Foo")
'Foo'
```

Comment: I know I can implement them myself. It's just that it would be nice functionality to have in the standard library, and it seems like it wouldn't make the api heavier. Maybe even lighten it. Though the all([]) case is a challenge.

Comment: @ThomasAhle, well you can specify a default value in that case, so choose a True or False value that suits your needs.