# How to find what matched in any() with Python?

Tags: python, any

I'm working in Python, using [any()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) like so to look for a match between a `String[]` array and a comment pulled from Reddit's API.

Currently, I'm doing it like this:

```
isMatch = any(string in comment.body for string in myStringArray)
```

But it would also be useful to not just know if `isMatch` is true, but which element of `myStringArray` it was that had a match. Is there a way to do this with my current approach, or do I have to find a different way to search for a match?

Comment: simply remove `any` and perform the check with explicit `for` loop. I don't see any issue here

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55889257/1179966

Answer (score 15):

You could use [`next`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) with a default of `False` on a conditional generator expression:

```
next((string for string in myStringArray if string in comment.body), False)
```

The default is returned when there is no item  that matched (so it's like `any` returning `False`), otherwise the first matching item is returned.

This is roughly equivalent to:

```
isMatch = False  # variable to store the result
for string in myStringArray:
    if string in comment.body:
        isMatch = string
        break  # after the first occurrence stop the for-loop.
```

or if you want to have `isMatch` and `whatMatched` in different variables:

```
isMatch = False  # variable to store the any result
whatMatched = '' # variable to store the first match
for string in myStringArray:
    if string in comment.body:
        isMatch = True
        whatMatched = string
        break  # after the first occurrence stop the for-loop.
```

Comment: Is it really a good idea to store *either* a bool or the matched string in the same variable? This seems to be taking dynamic types way too far.

Comment: `any` can be understood immediately just by looking at it. A `for` loop wouldn't be much worse. I've been looking at this for a minute and still can't convince myself that it works; that makes it a bad solution.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've included a version without `next` that should be equivalent. Just in case it helps to understand what's happening. :)

Comment: in Python 3.8, next takes no keyword arguments, but default is a positional argument instead.  So `next((shizzle for shizzle in english if shizzle in websters), False)`

Comment: @brianpck i think this first one-line solution is fine, as long as you replace the `False` with `None`. `None` is a sensible 'no value found' response, which can then be used via `if match is None: ...`

Answer (score 10):

For python 3.8 or newer use [Assignment Expressions](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

```
if any((match := candidate) in comment.body for candidate in candidates):
    print(match)
```

Comment: If having to access `candidate.foo`, it can be accessed as say `getattr((match := candidate), 'foo')`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good idea to use one variable to store two different kinds of information: *whether* a string matches (a `bool`) and *what* that string is (a `string`).

You really only need the second piece of information: while there are creative ways to do this in one statement, as in the above answer, it really makes sense to use a `for` loop:

```
match = ''
for string in myStringArray:
    if string in comment.body:
        match = string
        break

if match:
    pass # do stuff
```

Comment: Put this into a function and it's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Say you have `a = ['a','b','c','d']` and `b = ['x','y','d','z']`,

so that by doing `any(i in b for i in a)` you get `True`.

You can get:

- The array of matches : `matches = list( (i in b for i in a) )`
- Where in `a` it first matches : `posInA = matches.index(True)`
- The value : `value = a[posInA]`
- Where in `b` it first matches : `posInB = b.index(value)`

To get *all* the values and their indexes, the problem is that `matches == [False, False, True, True]` whether the multiple values are in `a` or `b`, so you need to use enumerate in loops (or in a list comprehension).

```
for m,i in enumerate(a):
    print('considering '+i+' at pos '+str(m)+' in a')
    for n,j in enumerate(b):
        print('against '+j+' at pos '+str(n)+' in b')
        if i == j:
            print('in a: '+i+' at pos '+str(m)+', in b: '+j+' at pos '+str(n))
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comment that an explicit loop would be clearest.  You *could* fudge your original like so:

```
isMatch = any(string in comment.body and remember(string) for string in myStringArray)
                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

where:

```
def remember(x):
    global memory
    memory = x
    return True
```

Then the global `memory` will contain the matched string if `isMatch` is `True`, or retain whatever value (if any) it originally had if `isMatch` is `False`.

Comment: I hope this is intended humorously for the problem the OP is trying to solve :)

Comment: Globals are evil. If you really want to use this technique, create a class object with a member to remember the match.