# how to use Assignment Expressions to check what was matched by any()

Tags: python

I am confused with Assignment Expressions (https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/). According to this question ([How to find what matched in any() with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41728329/how-to-find-what-matched-in-any-with-python)) I can use Assignment Expressions to find what was matched by any().

Simple example:

```py
look = "abc"

mylist = ["abcde15", "nonono"]

if any((match := look) in s for s in mylist):
    print(f"I found {look} v {mylist}")

# I found abc v ['abcde15', 'nonono']
```

But how can I get `abcde15` which is what I found in mylist? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning `match` to be the value of `look`, which is always `"abc"`, hence your result. Instead, you want to figure out which `s` in `mylist` was the match, which you can do by using that assignment expression on `s` instead:

```
look = "abc"

mylist = ["abcde15", "nonono"]

if any(look in (match := s) for s in mylist):
    print(f"I found {match} v {mylist}")
```

Which outputs

```
I found abcde15 v ['abcde15', 'nonono']
```