# Pandas Series any() vs all()

Tags: python, pandas, series

```
>>> s = pd.Series([float('nan')])
>>> s.any()
False
>>> s.all()
True
```

Isn't that weird? Documentation on [any](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html) (Return whether any element is True over requested axis) and [all](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.all.html) (Return whether all elements are True over requested axis) is similar, but the difference in behavior doesn't seem to make sense to me.

What gives?

Comment: Perhaps it's actually doing *"no elements are false"*, rather than *"all elements are true"*, and `nan` makes it three-valued logic?

Comment: @jonrsharpe, i guess NaN's will be ignored altogether in this case - check this: `pd.Series([]).any()` and `pd.Series([]).all()`

Comment: Yes, this is likely an issue with how `pandas` deals with NaN by default.

Comment: What i can't understand is why does: `pd.Series([]).all()` give `True`, `all([])` also returns `True` (and i can't understand this as well...)

Comment: Found this question that delves into it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275058/reason-for-all-and-any-result-on-empty-lists

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks for that link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with how `pandas` normally ignores `NaN` unless told not to:

```
>>> pd.Series([float('nan')]).any()
False
>>> pd.Series([float('nan')]).all()
True
>>> pd.Series([float('nan')]).any(skipna=False)
True
>>>
```

Note, `NaN` is falsey:

```
>>> bool(float('nan'))
True
```

Also note: this is consistent with the built-in `any` and `all`. Empty iterables return `True` for `all` and `False` for `any`. [Here is a relevant question on that topic.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275058/reason-for-all-and-any-result-on-empty-lists)

Interestingly, the default behavior appears to be inconsistent with the documentation:

> skipna : boolean, default True
>           Exclude NA/null values. If an entire row/column is NA, the result
>           will be NA

But observe:

```
>>> pd.Series([float('nan')]).any(skipna=None)
False
>>> pd.Series([float('nan')]).any(skipna=True)
False
>>> pd.Series([float('nan')]).any(skipna=False)
True
>>>
```

Comment: The documentation says the following about `skipna`: `Exclude NA/null values. If an entire row/column is NA, the result will be NA`. And it doesn't work that way: `pd.Series([float('nan')]).any()` returns `False`, not `NA`.

Comment: @DennisGolomazov Yes, I was about to post that.

Comment: This just seems to be inconsistent, `skipna` is True by default in both `any` and `all`, so if `all` is True, `any` should be True too, shouldn't it?

Comment: @DennisGolomazov No, it seems to be consistent with the builtin `any` and `all`. Empty iterables return `True` for `all` and `False` for `any`. See the discussion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275058/reason-for-all-and-any-result-on-empty-lists)

Comment: Good call, you might want to add that to the answer itself.

Comment: @DennisGolomazov went ahead and did that. I wonder if anyone has found this inconsistency with the documentation before? It seems like a sort of arcane corner. In any event, most of the `pandas` api ignores `NaN` by default, so maybe no one has been surprised by it yet...

Comment: Answer accepted, thank you! Yes, generally I find pandas documentation to be poorly organized. I tend to find most of the answers on SO, not in the docs.

Comment: Heh. Yeah, [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) is my favorite example of a very 'helpful' pandas documentation...