# Why don't Array.prototype.some() return true for an empty set?

Tags: javascript

I just found this piece on the MDN page for `Array.prototype.every()`:

> `every` acts like the "for all" quantifier in mathematics. In particular, for an empty array, it returns true. (It is [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth) that all elements of the empty set satisfy any given condition.)

This is indeed the case, as we can see:

```js
console.log([].every(a => a === "any possible value here"))
```

However:

```js
console.log([].some(a => a === "any possible value here"))
```

#### Question:

Risking to be closed as *opinion based*, this is my question: why didn't ECMA chose to treat `Array.prototype.some()`'s callback as vacuously true for an empty array?

The way I see it, if *"it is vacuously true that all elements of the empty set satisfy any given condition"*, as the MDN page says, then it follows that *"it is vacuously true that **any** element of the empty set satisfy any given condition"*. For instance, if we use Wikipedia's example,

> all cell phones in the room are turned on and turned off

We are allowed to say that *"some cell phones in the room are turned off"* is equaly (and vacuously) true. Isn't that the case?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3275058/reason-for-all-and-any-result-on-empty-lists

Comment: It's also vacuously true that there exists no member in an empty set that satisfied any given condition. I'd interpret "some cell phones in the room are turned off" as "is there any cellphone in this room that is turned off".

Comment: The analogy is wrong here. The correct analogy would be "there's some cell phone in this room that is turned off". It might be the only one or it might not be, the point is **it exists**. On the other hand all cell phones in the room *could* be 0

Comment: *some* is generally a positive assertion that there is *at least one* of something or other. An empty set fulfilling that wouldn't make much sense.

Comment: @Megapteranovaeangliae: "every" is basically the negation of "some" with a negated condition: "every(condition)" means "not(some(not(condition))". If that is accepted as a valid transformation, then it follows that "every" and "some" must provide opposite values on the empty set.

Comment: These are related to quantifiers. `Every` is the universal quantifier, `some` the existential. *Does there exist an object which ...* should be `false` for an empty set of objects.

Comment: Even if you can debate about the valid answer to the question *"does every item fulfil this condition"* for an empty set, even intuitively and linguistically the answer to *"does __any__ item fulfil this condition"* should be _no_ if there are no items.

Comment: I see. Thank you all, I'm flaging this as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `.every`, you're asking whether all items in a list fulfil a condition. If that list is empty, well, there are no items which do *not* fulfil the condition. Every item that there is (which is none) fulfils the given condition, so `.every` is vacuously true.

With `.some`, you're asking whether *any* item in a list fulfils a condition. If there are no items, then there's no item to fulfil the condition. So no, nothing in an empty list can fulfil the condition and it's vacuously false.